# Differentiate between ^J and <Enter> in curses

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I've noticed some curses applications (for instance `vim`) treat `^J` and `<Enter>` as the same keypress

I've also noticed that others treat them as separate keys (for instance `nano` which uses `^J` for "Justify")

In my particular case, I'm using `curses` through python, however both presses appear to give the same value

Here's a small demo application:

```
import curses


def c_main(stdscr):
    wch = ''
    while wch != 'q':
        stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'Press a key, q to quit: ')
        wch = stdscr.get_wch()
        key = wch if isinstance(wch, int) else ord(wch)
        keyname = curses.keyname(key)
        stdscr.insstr(1, 0, f'> got {wch!r} {key!r} {keyname!r}{" " * 80}')


def main():
    curses.wrapper(c_main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())
```

For both `^J` (control + J) and `<enter>` (enter key) I get the following:

```
Press a key, q to quit: 
> got '\n' 10 b'^J'
```

How can I differentiate these two?

Comment: [`curses.raw()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.raw) can let the application read `^M`

Comment: @ThomasDickey good hint!  `curses.nonl()` appears to be less intrusive and fixes this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting [`curses.nonl()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.nonl) disables translation of the `<enter>` key to `'\n'`

For example:

```
import curses


def c_main(stdscr):
    curses.nonl()
    wch = ''
    i = 1
    while wch != 'q':
        stdscr.addstr(0, 0, 'Press a key, q to quit: ')
        stdscr.keypad(False)
        wch = stdscr.get_wch()
        key = wch if isinstance(wch, int) else ord(wch)
        keyname = curses.keyname(key)
        stdscr.insstr(i, 0, f'> got {wch!r} {key!r} {keyname!r}{" " * 80}')
        i += 1


def main():
    curses.wrapper(c_main)
```

And then issuing `^J` followed by `<enter>`:

```
Press a key, q to quit: 
> got '\n' 10 b'^J'
> got '\r' 13 b'^M'
```